# Select last Week or Weekend from the current_date on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a little problem with PostgreSQL, i could do everything with CASE WHEN but I hope there is another method to do this.

In a few words I have to calculate an AVG value from the last week day, if NOW() is a week day (to_char(now(),'D') between 2 and 6) or from the last weekend day (in other case).

Example, for now (21/01/2021 dd/mm/aaaa) I need that my query give me 11/01/2021 00:00:00 - 15/01/2021 23:59:59.
Example, for next-tomorrow (23/01/2021) I need that my query give me 16/01/2021 00:00:00 -17/01/2021 23:59:59.

Does anybody know if I could do something with SQL?

Thank you,

Regards

EDIT:
I only need a query in which I select the current_date and it returns me the following range of date.

```
Select 
case when to_char(now(),'D') in (2,3,4,5,6) then --last working day week
else ----last weekend days
end
```

For the last working day I mean the range from the midnight of Monday to the 23:59:59 of Friday of the last week (for today, 21/01/2021, i need the 11/01/2021 00:00:00 - 15/01/2021 23:59:59) and for the last weekend days I mean the range from the midnight of Saturday to the 23:59:59 of Sunday

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: IF you have a date and want to get the first and last date of the same week - you just need to subtract the DOW (day of week) number of days from your date (so you get the Monday of the given week), and then add 7 days to get the Sunday.

Comment: I need the last week days, not the same week, and the range from Monday-Friday if now we are between Monday-Friday and the range from Saturday-Sunday if now we are between Saturday-Sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved!

```
select current_date - extract(isodow from current_date)::integer-6 as monday,
   current_date - extract(isodow from current_date)::integer-2 as friday,
   current_date - extract(isodow from current_date)::integer-1 as saturday,
   current_date - extract(isodow from current_date)::integer as sunday
```

It worked for all date. I only have to use case when to chose the different 2 select statements.

Thank you all